# Can Linux make a process disappear?

Tags: linux, kernel, process

One of my processes got killed by OOM killer which made me think, why does Linux kernel even bother with sending a SIGKILL? I mean I know why, to kill the process in an orderly manner.

Nevertheless, does the Linux kernel have the capability to just... delete the process? In a way that no other process can find out what happened to the removed process? Remove the entry in the appropriate vectors and structs and continue on?

Presumably, this would leave all other processes depending on reasonable behavior of this process in a dangerous state. But that seems fair, given the unreasonableness of such action. To be clear, this question is much more "can we do this?" as opposed to should we do this. I promise I'm not going to be doing this on production database servers.

Comment: Yes, of course the OS could do that, but how would messing up the rest of the system "seem fair"? It would be quite counterproductive for anyone who wants to actually use the system for getting something _done_. If you were going to do that, you might as well just reboot, which would at least let the system recover to a known state...

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I can still see some usefulness in the answer to this question. First of all, from OS engineering perspective, it would be interesting to see how it works and what would happen afterwards. Secondly, given an unreasonable state already, for example during infection by malware or some kind of Kernel bug, or OOM, this might be actually useful. Yeah I know data corruption, freezing and painting my mustache blue are all possible outcomes. Unreasonable outcomes seem fair for such an unreasonable action.

Comment: @ilkkachu Additionally, I do not appreciate the condescending manner of this comment, as I have clearly stated that I know it's a very bad idea and am just curious from sysadmin point of view.

Comment: well, your original post said _"this would leave all other processes depending on reasonable behavior of this process in a dangerous state but that seems fair."_ Nothing there said anything to indicate you thought it was a bad idea, quite the contrary, really. Really, that what you wrote the (everything before the "but") explains exactly why the OS doesn't do that, and the assertion that it "seems fair" appears quite outlandish. Now, I see you edited it to something more reasonable now, but that's not what the post said at first, so...

Comment: Okay well fair. Anyway yeah I know

Answer (score 1):

Processes do not exist in a vacuum. They have a parent, maybe children, processes waiting for them. They could also be holding onto resources needed by others ...

So, *just* disappear would not work, there is lots of work involved and you have to notify other parts of the system.

Why send a signal instead of simply *just doing* it right away? Well, it's a clean way and you can reuse the logic. An uncaught `SIGTERM` (or a any caught signal followed by exit for example) will do more or less the same. You also get a coherent way to report that to the parent and just one piece of code handling all those situations.

Comment: Yup yup I know that its a bad idea. I understand that even kill -9 is a bad idea. But I still find it intriguing. What would happen to the children processes whos parent would be yanked in such a way? What would happen to the open ports, to the memory? Would the memory be reported as "free" even though it wasn't. Would `top` just crash?

Comment: @Richard that's up to you to define. What did you mean when you said "remove the entries from the appropriate vectors"? If that includes closing sockets, well, then that includes closing sockets, for example.

Comment: Yeah that's fair. What if we didn't do any of that? All of a sudden we have many blocked resources which appear unused by anyone. Is there any "kernel garbage collector" which goes around and checks these things? Would another process which happens to have the same PID suddenly gain ownership of all of the memory?

Comment: This is all probably undefined behavior and I would need to patch the kernel to try it wouldn't I

Comment: @Richard If you want to modify the kernel to just yank out a process without regard to its allocated resources, it would seem reasonable for the changes to include closing file descriptors, deallocating memory, releasing file descriptors, etc. Sounds like a lot more work than sending a `SIGTERM` and letting well-tested routines handle the details. Are you looking for some well-defined benefit to the abrupt disappearance of a process?

Comment: I don't have the time for patching the kernel right now, but it might be an interesting first exercise. And I don't really see any benefit except for learning about the kernel and how things can go wrong when they go wrong.

Comment: You learn nothing about "how things can go wrong" by deliberately putting data structures at odd with the content of other data structures and reality because you didn't do the clean up.

Comment: I believe you do. Assume that after that, ext4 for some reason causes a kernel panic. Now I will investigate, how did a missing process cause a file system to crash? Is it reasonable to expect a filesystem stability to depend on process stability? Or perhaps, one could find that actually, everything got tidied up by some kind of sentinels and kernel is much more robust than I previously thought. This could be a fascinating exercise.

Comment: again: it's up to you to define how you break consistency. Your choices there define what breaks. It's really not my authority to define what you find fascinating, but I think you'll learn very little about operating systems by trying out what happens when you start referencing things that aren't there anymore, not because a proper lifecycle let them disappear, but because some deliberately yanked them out. How much do you learn about car design when you cut brake lines?